# Unable to read new line of a file

Tags: c++, file, io

I'm quite new to C++ programming, and I'm having trouble reading from an already open file. What I'm doing is writing to a file, reading from it, adding to the end of it, and then trying to read from it again without having to close the original ifstream. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream myFile ("example.dat");

    // Open and write to file
    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        myFile << "This is a line." << endl;
        myFile << "This is another line." << endl;
        myFile.close();
    }
    else cout << "no";

    // Open and read from file
    string line;
    ifstream myFilein ("example.dat");
    if (myFilein.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myFilein,line))
        {
            cout << line << myFilein.tellg() << endl;
        }
        //myFilein.close();
    }

    // Open and add to end of file
    if (!myFile.is_open())
    {
        myFile.open("example.dat", ios::app);
        myFile << "This is the last line." << endl;
        myFile.close();
    }

    //myFilein.open("example.dat", ios::ate);

    // Read from already open file
    myFilein.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    if (myFilein.is_open())
    {
        cout << "myFilein is open. " << myFilein.tellg() << endl;
        while (!myFilein.eof())
        {
            getline(myFilein, line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    myFilein.close();

    int holdClose;
    cin >> holdClose;

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, something is going wrong, as tellg() is returning a value of -1 after the initial read (i.e., after it hits the end of the file), but I'm not entirely sure why it's returning -1, since I'm trying to reset the position to the beginning of the file. Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding about how this works? If I close and re-open the file, then it's fine, but I'm curious if there's a way to keep reading from it without having to close it, if that makes sense. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Once the file has error flags on it, like `eof`, you need to use `myFilein.clear()` to reset them if you want to continue to work with the file.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clear the state of the stream, thus the `seekg` call did nothing. You need to add `myFilein.clear()` before the repositioning.